# WebApi controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I try to integrate autofac for webapi and I am having problem to make it work. 
My controller constructor signature is:

```cs
public class AController: ApiController
{
  public AController(IComponentContext componentContext)
  {}
}
```

In my global.asax file i have called the following code in Application_Start

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   builder.RegisterApiControllers();
   container = builder.Build();
   var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

}

When I try to run my application and to access my ressource "/api/A", the server returns an error 500 complaining about the fact the controller does not have a default constructor. I though that was the task of the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver to inject the container in my case. How can I fix my issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my issue .

Update this line to

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

sort the issue out.